# Scope of Callback with $http when using $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, callback

I'm using `$http` to get data from my server inside my controller but it's not really working as I would like.

on my view i'm using data fron `$scope.data` that need to be pulled from the api, but when i'm doing this :

```
$http({method: 'GET',url: url}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.data = response.xx.yy.map(function(item) {
    return item.zz;
  });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

It's like `$scope.data` doesn't even exist in my view. console logging the response works but i can't go much further.

I've tried to :

- create a global var outside of my controller and using it inside my callback but that doesn't work , probably because it's asyncronous i'm getting undefined when called outside of the callback
- using `$scope.$parent`
- creating a global var inside my callback  `data = reponse` , doesn't work either.

I'm starting to belive it got to do with the fact the it's asyncronous or maybe something else about angular but can't really figure out what/why.

edit :

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('PaCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor','$timeout','$stateParams','$http',function ($scope, $meteor, $timeout,$stateParams,$http) {
  var url = '/api/'+$stateParams.ID.toString()
  $http({method: 'GET',url: url}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response)//work
    $scope.friends = response.data.users[0].friends.map(function(item) {
      return item.name;
    });
    $scope.age = response.data.users[0].friends.map(function(item) {
      return item.age;
    });
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
  console.log($scope.friends) // undefined
  console.log($scope.age) // undefined
}]);
```

html :

```
<div ng-controller="PaCtrl">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <canvas    height="80"
        id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" 
        chart-legend="false" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas> 
      </div>
</div>
```

routes :

```
angular.module('MyApp').config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('users', {
            url: '/users/:userID',
            templateUrl: '/template.html'
        })
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code. Also, have you added logs in success function to print `$scope.data`.

Comment: I think you should use `$scope.data = response.data.xx.yy`..where I'm particularly accessing data from `response` object.. any console error?

Comment: Try this : $scope.a = {data:{}}; and assign your data to $scope.a.data and change your HTML accordingly. If it works that means that a directive was messing with your scope. If it doesn't work, show your HTML and route/state definition.

Comment: Still getting Object {} when i console.log $scope.a.data from outside the .then callback.  Getting the proper value when called inside the callback. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.data = {};

$http({method: 'GET',url: url}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.data = response;
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  console.log('Error', response);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

If it works add the rest of the code.

Comment: Could you `console.log(response)`?

Comment: I did and i get the proper response object with my data

Answer (score 0):

## Whats your data structure

You may be getting an array from your api. Thats why it shows up on log but not in your view.

Try setting scope with a 0 index in your call back like

```
Var data = response.xx. //etc.
$scope.data = data[0];
```

Same thing happened to me before, hope this helps.

## Note on app structure

Just an extra thing, you should make your http calls in a factory and then call that in your controller. Keeps a good seperation of concerns and makes code allot more readable.

Comment: It is an array but saddly that's not the issue i just made the example simplier for SO. See my edit

Comment: console log your data after the request and post the full response

Comment: I console logged the data and it's fine when inside the callback i can access to whatever i want. It's just outside that it's messed up and cant even get the whole reponse or anything.